# How would I write a String directly to S3 in Java?

Tags: java, amazon-s3

Is there a way to write a `String` directly to S3, without first having to write it to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will end up in a "file", because S3 is a directory structure. But you can write it via a string/stream/reader, if your api allows it.

For example, the [jets3t](http://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.html) API has this (s3Key is the key it is stored under in s3. Filename, in other words)

```
s3service.putObject(bucketName, new S3Object(s3Key, yourString));
```